# Subtract String List Elements from 2 lists

Tags: python, string, list, math, operation

I have the following code, which works fine for adding string elements from 2 lists:

```
list_1 = ['2 Red', '8 Blue', '4 Green']
list_2 = ['10 Red', '2 Blue', '3 Green']

list_1.extend(list_2)

results = {}

for elem in list_1:
    number, color = elem.split()
    results[color] = results.get(color, 0) + int(number)

result = [f"{i} {p}" for i, p in zip(results.values(), results.keys())]

Output: ['12 Red', '10 Blue', '7 Green']
```

Now, I want to do basic subtraction for the same elements, that the output is as follows:

```
Output: ['8 Red', '6 Blue', '1 Green']
```

I thought I understood my code, but obviously  I don't, I get stuck with the + operator for int(numbers) & I do not understand the zip() function. I hope you guys can help me.

Stay healthy and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

We use `int` for addition since the data to add is a string after the `split` operation.

Secondly, we use `zip` method to iterate the dictionary elements together in a single loop.

Further, you can use `abs` function to get the absolute value for the second part of the problem:

```
list_1 = ['2 Red', '8 Blue', '4 Green']
list_2 = ['10 Red', '2 Blue', '3 Green']
list_1.extend(list_2)

results = {}

for elem in list_1:
    number, color = elem.split()
    results[color] = abs(int(number) - results.get(color, 0) )

result = [f"{i} {p}" for i, p in zip(results.values(), results.keys())]

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it solved my problem, but I wonder if it is possible to do the same operation without mergin these two lists?

Comment: `zip()` function returns a `zip` object, which is an `iterator` of tuples so we aren't really merging the list at any place